# AdMob not showing in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, admob

I'm trying adding AdMob in my webview but no works at well.. In my main.xml i wrote this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           ads:adSize="BANNER"
                           ads:adUnitId="1234567890"
                           ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in the mainifest i added:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

When i run the application the banner not showing and the logcat says: `onFailedToReceiveAd(Invalid Ad request.)` i think the problem is the ID but i can't understand which id i have to write! My ID's in "AdMob console" are only with number and not something like `a14f3ed10a5e4eb`

EDIT:
i tryied write:

```
ca-app-pub-****************/**********
```

where * are numbers. The banner appears but disappears after some seconds..

Answer (score 0):

The Admob AdUnitId you should be using should look like:

```
ca-app-pub-****************/**********
```

So you were on the right track.

You will get

```
onFailedToReceiveAd(Invalid Ad request.)
```

when there are no ads available to show.